# C# using object "alias"

Tags: c#

```
// actual
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// looking for
using Deps.Base; // containing the above
```

I'm trying to "alias" these objects without additional overhead. Can't find the name for what I'm trying to do, and am wondering if I would be adding overhead with it.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible. There could be types within those namespaces that share the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JohnathanBarclay. Perhaps, something like c++ macros where a bunch of text is literally copied in? With directives or whatever

Comment: The first 3 `using`-s all refer to **namespaces**. Each namespace can define lots and lots of classes. And there is no way in the C# language to bundle namespaces. If you have a good modern IDE then it is very easy to get the correct `using`-s. You need to get used to (instead of considering it a poblem) that the same bunch of `using`-s are repeated in many places.

Comment: `using RenamedObject = MyNamespace.Subnamepsace.MyObject`. This is what you can do in C# with [using alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

Comment: Thank you all for answers.

@PeterB I appreciate the info you've given (I'm noob enough in c# not to know those are necessarily namespaces), though I gotta point out that IS a problem. I CAN get used to it, but it still IS a problem ;) Simply signal to noise ratio. Kevin Henney iirc had a bunch of talks on the matter.

Comment: @PeterB here it is https://youtu.be/FyCYva9DhsI?t=1679 (starting around at 28min mark)

Comment: C# has no builtin shorthand for "importing usings", no macro support and no preprocessor directive like "#include". If you're using razor though, there is a Import-Directive. For Razor pages only though. And I've gotten used to it. It is no problem, as there is a lot of "clutter" in a regular C# file anyways (even if done correctly), usings don't stand out particularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're planning to do is not possible due to the overlapping/crossing of types sharing the same name in the namespace unfortunately.

Comment: if you found that answer as successful then please upvote it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bundle using statements in C#.
You'll almost never need to look at those statements though. Most IDE's will add them automatically and have procedures to clean them up automatically.

If you use Visual Studio and you don't want to see them you can collapse them.
There are extensions that automatically collapse (hide) them every time you open a cs file:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Nhitze.SeeUsingsLater
I don't have any experience with this extension though. Personally, I'm not bothered by the using statements at the top.